# How do I paste an image onto another image?

Tags: android, image, overlay

I would like to take one image, and then paste it onto another image using Bitmap. (Basically overlaying image 1 on top of image 2 and then being able to save it.)

I've been searching all day for this. Are there any tutorials that show this? I couldn't find any functions in the Android SDK that did this either.

Comment: do you mean that after putting the image2 onto image1.you just want to store the image2. RIGHT?

Comment: I want to store image z after putting image y onto image z. Something like that. It's kind of confusing.

Comment: you can simple make an arraylist of images.and before showing the image on the imageview,put the the previous image inside the arraylist.in this way u can save multiple images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine two bitmaps like this

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: What if you need to move one of the image's coordinates?